# Как установить цветовую схему vim?

Tags: vim

https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes/blob/master/vim-themes/colors/Iceberg.vim

Достаточно ли просто скопипастить это в конкретную папку, а затем подключить `:colorscheme themename`?
При таком подходе дефолтовые темы у меня отображаются верно, но кастомные отображаются абсолютно не так. Например, конкретно та, что выше, представляет из себя полностью белый текст.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip341 вот хороший plugin.

Comment: Странная она какая-то. Поместил эту канитель в ~/.vim/colors/Iceberg.vim

    :colorscheme Iceberg

(причём автодополнение до Icberg работает). Но схема не понравилась (не говоря уж про то, что в текстовом режиме её вообще не видать, только в gui).

Comment: Рекомендую попробовать вот эти темы для вима: [Molokai](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai) [Solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized)

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, да, достаточно положить тему в папку. Обычно это `.vim/colors/` и потом прописать, например, `color wombat256`.

Во-вторых, самое главное - нормальные темы для своей работы требуют 256-колор режим, без него вы не сможете насладиться темой в полной мере.

Чтобы включить 256-й режим, надо прописать в `.vimrc`:

```
" 256-color terminal
set t_Co=256
" тему можно также поставить прямо в .vimrc
color wombat256
```

И не забыть после этого перезапустить vim.

Answer (score 1):

При запуске Вима в терминалах вроде Gnome Terminal, Konsole следует использовать `:colorsheme default` и настраивать цветовую схему при помощи средств самого терминала (настройки профиля - цвета). Все остальные темы в терминале чаще всего отображаются некорректно.

А за интересную ссылку на множество тем для Вима очень большое спасибо :)